# Pass complex data between react native android modules

Tags: java, android, react-native

My app is for android platform only so I need only the android part.

I have 2 custom views (lets call them `CustomView0` and `CustomView1`) and 2 view manager classes (`CustomViewManager0` and `CustomViewManager1`) for them. They are placed in scene 0 and scene 1 in my react native application.

I use react native's `Navigator` component for navigation. `CustomView0` collects and provides some data of type `CustomData`. And `CustomView1` can take that data with `setData(CustomData data)` method.

Now I need to take collected `CustomData` object from `CustomView0` in scene 0 and pass it to scene 1's `CustomView1`.

I have a couple of ideas but not sure they are good:

1. Serialize my `CustomData` as a json, take that json string in javascript from `CustomViewManager0`, pass it to my scene 1 component as a property and set it to `CustomViewManager1`. `CustomViewManager1` will take the json string, parse it to `CustomData` object and pass it to `CustomView1`.
2. Create a singleton `DataTransmitter` java class which has a `Map<String, Object>` of data in it. `CustomViewManager0` will set the data with some key and `CustomViewManager1` will take that data with the same key and cast to `CustomData`

I'd appreciate if someone tells me a better way to achieve this.